# Why won't my PHP MySQLi Query insert to Database?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

PHP Version:    5.4.3
MySQLi Version: 5.5.24

I've been staring at this code for a few days now, fixed a lot of minor errors and still can't figure out why it won't successfully add to my database.

Broken Code:

```
// All of my posts have been excluded
// Post Example:
// $server = $_POST['server'];

mysqli_query($link, sprintf(
    'INSERT INTO `tribe-server-inv`.`serverdb` (' .

    //Server Name
    '`Record`, `Server`, `Active Server`, `Server Location`, `Deactivated Server`, ' .

    //System Overview
    '`Operating System`, `Serial Number`, `Model`, `CPU`, `Power Requirements`, `Location`, `Memory`, ' .
    '`Total Physical Disk`, ' .

    //System Information
    '`Antivirus Installed`, `Warrenty Start Date`, `Physical Server`, `Install Date`, `Antivirus Version`, ' . 
    '`Warrenty End Date`, `Virtual Server`, `Deactivated Date`, ' .

    //Availability
    '`Operation Availability Days`, `Availability Downtime Days`, `Operation Availability Hours`, ' .
    '`Availability Downtime Hours`, ' .

    //Support Information
    '`Hardware Vender`, `Associated Servers 1`, `System Owner`, `Associated Servers 2`, ' .
    '`Database Owner`, `Associated Servers 3`, `Application Owner`, `Associated Servers 4`, ' .
    '`Software Owner`, `Associated Servers 5`, ' .

    //Network Info
    '`IP Address 1`, `MAC Address 1`, `Trunked IP Address 1`, `IP Address 2`, `MAC Address 2`, ' .
    '`Trunked IP Address 2`, `IP Address 3`, `MAC Address 3`, `Management Port IP Address`, ' .
    '`IP Address 4`, `MAC Address 4`, ' .

    //Storage Info
    '`Sans Storage 1`, `Sans Storage 1 Drive Space 1`, `Sans 1 Initiator Address`, `Sans Storage 2`, ' .
    '`Sans Storage 2 Drive Space 2`, `Sans 2 Initiator Address`, ' .
    '`Promise Storage 1`, `Promise Storage 1 Drive Space 1`, `Promise 1 Initiator Address`, ' .
    '`Promise Storage 2`, `Promise Storage 2 Drive Space 2`, `Promise 2 Initiator Address`, ' .

    //System Backup
    '`Appassure`, `Backupexec`, `Other Backup`, `Backup Server`, `Replication Backup Server`, ' .
    '`Backup Server Location`, `Replication Backup Location`, `Backup Server Size`, ' .
    '`Replication Backup Size`, `Offsite / Archive Backups`, `Backup Image`, `Archive Offsite Location`, ' .
    '`Backup Image Location`, `Archive Size`, `Backup Misc Info`, `Backup Daily`, ' .
    '`Daily Backup Space Used`, `Backup Weekly`, `Weekly Backup Space Used`, `Backup Quarterly`, ' .
    '`Quarterly Backup Space Used`, `Backup Yearly`, `Yearly Backup Space Used`, ' .

    //Disaster Recovery
    '`Number of Users`, `Daily Bandwidth Consumption`, `Equipment Replacement Time`, ' .
    '`Total Local Data Storage`, `Vender Disaster Turn Around`, `Vender Disaster Cost`, ' .
    '`Total Network Storage`, `Approximate Tech Hours`, `Est Replacement Cost`, ' .
    '`Approximate Total Replacement Time`, `Disaster Recovery Scenario 1 Loss of Software`, ' .
    '`Disaster Recovery Scenario 2 Loss of Hardware`, `Application`)' .

    //Values
    'VALUES ' .

    //Server Name
    '(NULL, \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', ' .

    //System Overview
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', ' .

    //System Information
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', ' .
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', ' .

    //Availability
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', ' .

    //Support Information
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', ' .
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', ' .

    //Network Info
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', ' .

    //Storage Info
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', ' .
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', ' .
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', ' .
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', ' .

    //System Backup
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', ' .
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', ' .
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', ' .
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', ' .

    //Disaster Recovery
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', ' .
    '\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\')',

    //Names
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $server),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $activeServer),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $serverLocation),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $deactiveServer),

    //Overview
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $operating),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $serial),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $model),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $cpu),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $powerReq),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $location),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $memory),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $totPhyDisk),

    //System Info
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $antiVirusInstall),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $warrentyStart),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $phyServer),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $installDate),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $antiVirusVersion),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $warrentyExpire),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $virtualServer),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $deactivatedDate),

    //Availability
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $availableDays),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $downtimeDays),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $availableHours),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $downtimeHours),

    //Support Info
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $hardwareVendor),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $assoServ1),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $systemOwner),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $assoServ2),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $databaseOwn),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $assoServ3),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $appOwner),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $assoServ4),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $softwareOwn),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $assoServ5),

    //Network Info
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $IP1),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $MAC1),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $trunk1),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $IP2),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $MAC2),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $trunk2),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $IP3),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $MAC3),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $manPortIP),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $IP4),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $MAC4),

    //Storage
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $sanStor1),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $driveSpace1),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $initiatorAddress1),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $sanStor2),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $driveSpace2),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $initiatorAddress2),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $promStor1),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $promStorSpace1),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $prom1InitAddress),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $promStor2),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $promStorSpace2),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $prom2InitAddress),

    //System Backup
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $appAssure),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $backupExec),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $otherBackup),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $backupServ),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $repBackupServ),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $backupServLoc),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $repBackupLoc),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $backupSize),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $repBackupSize),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $archiveBackup),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $backupImage),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $arcOffsiteLoc),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $backupImageLoc),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $arcBackSize),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $backupMiscInfo),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $backupDaily),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $dailySpaceUsed),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $backupWeekly),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $weeklySpaceUsed),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $backupQuarter),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $quarterlySpaceUsed),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $backupYear),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $yearlySpaceUsed),

    //Disaster Recovery
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $numUsers),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $bandwidth),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $equipReplaceTime),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $totalLocStor),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $vendorTurn),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $venDisCost),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $totNetStor),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $approxTechTime),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $estRepCost),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $totReplaceTime),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $disasterRecover1),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $disasterRecover2),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Applications)));
```

Working Code:

```
      mysqli_query($link, sprintf(
    'INSERT INTO serverdb (' .

    //Server Name
    'Server,' .
    '`Server Location`)' .

    //Values
    'VALUES ' .

    //Server Name
    '(\'%s\', \'%s\')',

    //Names
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $server),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $serverLocation)));
```

Both sets of code are structured exactly the same and I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Does `mysqli_error($link)` print out anything?

Comment: use at least prepared statements instead of this sprintf monster...

Comment: Whoever designed this table, well ... really shouldn't be designing tables.

Comment: Oh, my goodness

Comment: I agree that the table needs redesigned. It was converted from a poorly structured Access Database and is pending optimization after this gets working. And mysqli_error($link) posts nothing. No errors in PHP Log or MySQL Logs.

Comment: can you echo the query, copy it and execute it manually?

Comment: `echo` the parsed query and have fun debugging it...

Comment: @AbrahamSustaita: As a matter of fact, they aren't really `mysql_*` functions but `mysqli_*` ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to time constraints, a table rebuild is out of the options for now.  The solution to this was not to fix the code above but to rewrite the entire query from scratch without the mysqli_real_escape_strings.

The query that I got working is posted below.  To some of your relief, I built another table from scratch for tracking client computers, and that code will be posted below.  That code will be the way I will redo the server one unless I find/make improvements before that.

```
$q  = 'INSERT INTO `tribe-server-inv`.`serverdb` (`Server`,'.
      '`Server Location`, `Operating System`, `CPU`, `Memory`, `Total Physical Disk`, 

`Serial Number`, `Model`, `Location`, `IP Address 1`, `IP Address 2`,'.
  '`IP Address 3`, `IP Address 4`, `Trunked IP Address 1`, `Trunked IP Address 2`, `Management Port IP Address`, `Physical Server`, `Virtual Server`, `Warrenty Start Date`, `Warrenty End Date`, `Active Server`, `Install Date`, `Deactivated Server`, `Deactivated Date`,'.
          '`Power Requirements`, `Sans Storage 1`, `Sans Storage 2`, `Sans Storage 1 Drive Space 1`, `Sans Storage 2 Drive Space 2`, `Sans 1 Initiator Address`, `Sans 2 Initiator Address`, `Promise Storage 1`,'.
          '`Promise Storage 2`, `Promise Storage 1 Drive Space 1`, `Promise Storage 2 Drive Space 2`, `Promise 1 Initiator Address`, `Promise 2 Initiator Address`, `Operation Availability Hours`, `Operation Availability Days`,'.
        '`Availability Downtime Days`, `Availability Downtime Hours`, `Application`, `Associated Servers 1`, `Associated Servers 2`, `Associated Servers 3`, `Associated Servers 4`, `Associated Servers 5`, `Hardware Vender`, `System Owner`, `Database Owner`, `Application Owner`, `Software Owner`, `MAC Address 1`, `MAC Address 2`, `MAC Address 3`,'.
        '`MAC Address 4`, `Backup Server`, `Backup Server Location`, `Backup Server Size`, `Replication Backup Server`, `Replication Backup Location`, `Replication Backup Size`, `Offsite / Archive Backups`, `Archive Offsite Location`, `Archive Size`, `Backup Daily`, `Backup Weekly`, `Backup Quarterly`, `Backup Yearly`, `Backup Misc Info`, `Backup Image`, `Backup Image Location`, `Disaster Recovery Scenario 1 Loss of Software`, `Disaster Recovery Scenario 2 Loss of Hardware`, `Daily Backup Space Used`, `Weekly Backup Space Used`, `Quarterly Backup Space Used`, `Yearly Backup Space Used`, `Antivirus Installed`, `Antivirus Version`, `Est Replacement Cost`, `Number of Users`,'.
        '`Daily Bandwidth Consumption`, `Total Local Data Storage`, `Total Network Storage`, `Equipment Replacement Time`, `Vender Disaster Turn Around`, `Vender Disaster Cost`, `Approximate Tech Hours`, `Approximate Total Replacement Time`, `Appassure`, `Backupexec`, `Other Backup`)'.
        'VALUES (\''.$server.'\', \''.$serverLocation.'\', \''.$operating.'\', \''.$cpu.'\', \''.$memory.'\', \''.$totPhyDisk.'\', \''.$serial.'\', \''.$model.'\', \''.$location.'\', \''.$IP1.'\', \''.$IP2.'\', \''.$IP3.'\', \''.$IP4.'\', \''.$trunk1.'\', \''.$trunk2.'\', \''.$manPortIP.'\', \''.$phyServer.'\', \''.$virtualServer.'\', \''.$warrentyStart.'\', \''.$warrentyExpire.'\', \''. $activeServer.'\', \''.$installDate.'\', \''.$deactiveServer.'\', \''.$deactivatedDate.'\', \''.$powerReq.'\', \''.$sanStor1.'\', \''.$sanStor2.'\', \''.$driveSpace1.'\', \''.$driveSpace2.'\', \''.$initiatorAddress1.'\', \''.$initiatorAddress2.'\', \''.$promStor1.'\', \''.$promStor2.'\', \''.$promStorSpace1.'\', \''.$promStorSpace2.'\', \''.$prom1InitAddress.'\', \''.$prom2InitAddress.'\', \''.$availableHours.'\', \''.$availableDays.'\', \''.$downtimeDays.'\', \''.$downtimeHours.'\', \''.$Applications.'\', \''.$assoServ1.'\', \''.$assoServ2.'\', \''.$assoServ3.'\', \''.$assoServ4.'\', \''.$assoServ5.'\', \''.$hardwareVendor.'\', \''.$systemOwner.'\', \''.$databaseOwn.'\', \''.$appOwner.'\', \''.$softwareOwn.'\', \''.$MAC1.'\', \''.$MAC2.'\', \''.$MAC3.'\', \''.$MAC4.'\', \''.$backupServ.'\', \''.$backupServLoc.'\', \''.$backupSize.'\', \''.$repBackupServ.'\', \''.$repBackupLoc.'\', \''.$repBackupSize.'\', \''.$archiveBackup.'\', \''.$arcOffsiteLoc.'\', \''.$arcBackSize.'\', \''.$backupDaily.'\', \''.$backupWeekly.'\', \''.$backupQuarter.'\', \''.$backupYear.'\', \''.$backupMiscInfo.'\', \''.$backupImage.'\', \''.$backupImageLoc.'\', \''.$disasterRecover1.'\', \''.$disasterRecover2.'\', \''.$dailySpaceUsed.'\', \''.$weeklySpaceUsed.'\', \''.$quarterlySpaceUsed.'\', \''.$yearlySpaceUsed.'\', \''.$antiVirusInstall.'\', \''.$antiVirusVersion.'\', \''.$estRepCost.'\', \''.$numUsers.'\', \''.$bandwidth.'\', \''.$totalLocStor.'\', \''.$totNetStor.'\', \''.$equipReplaceTime.'\', \''.$vendorTurn.'\', \''.$venDisCost.'\', \''.$approxTechTime.'\', \''.$totReplaceTime.'\', \''.$appAssure.'\', \''.$backupExec.'\', \''.$otherBackup.'\')';
```

New Client Code:

```
$sql    = "SELECT id FROM `tribe-server-inv`.`client_main` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
                        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

                        while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                        {
                            $id = $row['id']+1;
                        }


                        //Client Main
                        $q1 =   "INSERT INTO `tribe-server-inv`.`client_main` (`id` ,`serial` ,`make` ,`model` ," .
                                "`warrentyStart` ,`warrentyEnd` ,`status` ,`type`)VALUES (".$id." , '" .
                                $serial."', '".$make."', '".$model."','".$warrentyStart."', '".$warrentyExpire."', '".$status."', '".$type."');";

                        //Client Deploy
                        $q2 =   "INSERT INTO  `tribe-server-inv`.`client_deploy` (`id` , `ticket` ,`techID` ,`installDate` ,`updateDate`)".
                                "VALUES (".
                                "'".$id."',  '".$ticket."',  '".$tech."',  '".$installDate."',  '".$updateDate."');";

                        //Client Profile
                        $q3 =   "INSERT INTO  `tribe-server-inv`.`client_profile` (`id` ,`username` ,`department` ,`buildID` ,`notes`)" .
                                "VALUES (" .
                                "'".$id."' ,  '".$user."',  '".$department."',  '".$building."',  '".$notes."');";


                        //Client Hardware
                        $q4 =   "INSERT INTO  `tribe-server-inv`.`client_hardware` (" .
                                "`id` ,`cpu` ,`memory` ,`diskSpace1` ,`diskSpace2` ,`diskSpace3`)".
                                "VALUES (".
                                "'".$id."' ,  '".$cpu."',  '".$memory."',  '".$diskSpace1."',  '".$diskSpace2."',  '".$diskSpace3."');";

                        //Client Software
                        $q5 =   "INSERT INTO  `tribe-server-inv`.`client_software` (`id` ,`operating` ,`operating_license` ,`antivirus` ,".
                                "`antivirus_license` ,`office` ,`office_license`)".
                                "VALUES (".
                                "'".$id."',  '".$operating."',  '".$osLicense."',  '".$antivirusInstalled."',  '".$antivirusVersion."',".
                                "'".$officeVersion."',  '".$officeLicense."');";

                        //Client Network
                        $q6 =   "INSERT INTO  `tribe-server-inv`.`client_network` (`id` ,`ip` ,`physicalMAC` ,`wirelessMAC` ,`port` ,`dns1` ,".
                                "`dns2` ,`dns3` ,`dns4`)".
                                "VALUES (".
                                "'".$id."',  '".$ip."',  '".$phyMac."',  '".$wireMac."',  '".$port."',  '".$dns1."',  '".$dns2."',  '".$dns3."',  '".$dns4."');";
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you can see PHP errors.
   Create an intentional syntax error and see if you can find it in logs on on-screen. If can't - configure your PHP to either log errors or show them on-screen:

   ```
   error_reporting = E_ALL
   display_errors = On
   log_errors = On
   ```

   in php.ini or [other places](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)
2. Then make sure you can see PHP errors again.
3. Make sure you can see mysqli errors. Run ALL your queries this way:

   ```
   mysqli_query($link, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($link));
   ```
4. Watch the error and take appropriate action.

Comment: Could you please try to track down the error too? I'd really like to see if it's even possible.

Comment: Errors are reporting and logging, created an error in the last MySQLi_Real_Escape_String and the error shows up. Without the intentional error, no issues are displayed.

When trying the trigger_error(mysqli_error($link)), I get the error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$link' (T_VARIABLE) in ...\saveFunction.php on line 311

Comment: Ended up rewriting the entire query until someone gets time to rebuilt the database. Works fine now. Thanks for those who tried to help.